# Android Webview goback with loaddatawithbaseurl

Tags: java, android, webview

I am using loaddatawithbaseurl to load custom html that I generated from a api into a webview.  How can I go back to the previous page that was previously loaded with loaddatawithbaseurl?
Let's say I go:
Page1->Page2->Page3

How do I get back to Page2?

I tried wb.goback, but that just loads a white page.  Im kind of stumped on this. Does anyone know of a clear cut way to do this?

```
wb = (ObservableWebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
wb.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
wb.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
wb.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

String htmls = "<html><head></head><body>Page 1</body></html>";
wb.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmls, "text/html", "utf-8", "");

htmls = "<html><head></head><body>Page 2</body></html>";
wb.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmls, "text/html", "utf-8", "");

htmls = "<html><head></head><body>Page 3</body></html>";
wb.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmls, "text/html", "utf-8", "");


public void onBackPressed() {
wb.goback;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed ()
    {
        if (wb.isFocused() && wb.canGoBack()) 
        {
            wb.goBack();       
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    }
```